# doubly linked tail delete o(1) time

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, tail

Im trying to delete from the end of a linked list using a tail pointer, but I can't seem to get it.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} LinkedList;

// Deletes from the head of the list using a head                                 pointer
void doubly_head_delete(LinkedList *list)
{
    if (list->tail->prev == NULL)
    {
        list->head = list->head->next;
        list->head->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->prev->next = list->tail->next;
        list->tail->next->prev = list->tail->prev;
    }
}

// Deletes the tail of the list using a tail pointer
void doubly_tail_delete(LinkedList *list)
{
    if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
        return;
    if (list->head != list->tail)
    {
        list->tail = list->tail->prev;
        list->tail->next = NULL;
        list->tail = list->tail->prev;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    }
}
```

I don't think the tail delete function is working because I can't figure out how to properly free the tail. Also, im not  exactly sure how to set the tail pointer to the tail of the list. As for the head_delete(), it seems to be working but i am not sure exactly how, or if it is actually correct, or if it is just a coincidence that it works. Im still trying to learn this and the internet doesn't seem to have the best examples. Thanks

Comment: Your two delete functions should be absolutely identical, except "head" and "tail" should be reversed, and "next" and "prev" should be reversed.  If that is not the case, then one of them probably has a bug, right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the address before changing the pointer.

```
void doubly_tail_delete(LinkedList *list)
{
   if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
      return;
   if (list->head != list->tail)
   {
       node *todelete = list->tail;
       list->tail = list->tail->prev;
       list->tail->next = NULL;
       //the next line you had is wrong.
       //list->tail = list->tail->prev;
       free(todelete);
   }
   else
   {
      free(list->head); //free it here before setting as NULL otherwise you lose the reference.
      list->head = list->tail = NULL;
   }
}
```

You are also not freeing while deleting from head... And there were a few bugs on it.

```
void doubly_head_delete(LinkedList *list)
{
   if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
      return;

   if (list->tail->prev == NULL)
   {
       free(list->head);
       list->head = list->tail = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
       node *todelete = list->head;
       list->head = list->head->next;
       list->head->prev = NULL;
       free(todelete);
   }
}
```